# Make running python shell dump PYC or source code of imported module which was deleted accidentally?

Tags: python, import, terminal, module, pyc

So I was making a git repo for a python project I've been working on for about a month and encountered a bug in GitHub desktop that caused the entire repo to disappear completely. When this happened, I was running a python shell in the PyCharm terminal in that directory, running a function imported from a module, and that function is still running right now. Examining the directory in another terminal shows no sign on any PYC files, and I'm also so far unable to use pycharms local history tool.

Before I ran this function, I imported the module via:

```
from solve import *
```

I only really care about one file, solve.py, the module I imported.

Once I ctrl-c this function or it terminates, is there any possible way to get the contents of the source code or the PYC by entering commands to the python shell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This was a personal project and it would honestly be against my better judgement to spend time trying to redo completely it at this point. If there's another exchange where this question would be better suited please let me know.

Comment: pycharm local history should have your file. you said that it did not work. how did u try?

Comment: The feature was simple greyed out in the IDE. Is there a way I could recover the file from the localhistory binaries?